# How to sum two columns and assign the value to another column in Django models

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a Stock table in models and I want to add the sum of two columns(thus, balance b/d and received) and assign the value to another column(thus, total bal) for each item, and use it for another calculation. Please can someone help me?

I tried this in models.py:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    part_No = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    balance_bd = models.IntegerField(default='0', null = True)
    received = models.IntegerField(default='0', null = True)
    total_bal = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    issued = models.IntegerField(default='0', null=True)
    tally_card_bal = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,  decimal_places=3, null=True)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,  decimal_places=3, null=True)
    obsolete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)

    def addTotalBal(self):
        self.total_bal = self.balance_bd + self.received
        return super(Stock, self).save()

     def addTallyCardBal(self):
         self.tally_card_bal = self.total_bal - self.issued
         return super(Stock, self).save()

     def addTotalPrice(self):
        self.total_price = self.tally_card_bal * self.unit_price
        return super(Stock, self).save()

     def __str__(self):
         return self.item_name
```

view.py:

```
def addItem(request):
    form = AddItemForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Stock.objects.create(part_No=request.POST.get('part_No'), item_name=request.POST.get('item_name'), category=request.POST.get('category'), unit=request.POST.get('unit'), balance_bd=request.POST.get('balance_bd'), received=request.POST.get('received'), issued=int(request.POST.get('issued')), unit_price=request.POST.get('unit_price'))
        return redirect('stock')

    context={
        'title':'Add Item',
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'base/add-item.html', context)
```

Comment: Are you sure those variables that start with "total" should not be properties? If they are calculated each time maybe this would be a better option.

Comment: Please which variables are you talking about?

Comment: `total_bal`, `total_price`, and `tally_card_bal`

Comment: I don’t really know oo. I watched a tutorial and I tried that but it didn’t work. 
Please can you explain to me what you mean by it should be a properties?

Comment: I will add an answer because it's too long to write this all in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposition is to use *computed properties* instead of model attributes.

The difference between the two is that computed properties are NOT stored as a DB table column and are calculated in the Python code every time you access them. Regular model attributes represent table columns and are stored in the DB.

If you store these things in the DB, you will have to update the values every time one of the other values are changed. However, since the value of the `total_bal`, `total_price`, and `tally_card_bal` can always be directly calculated from other variables, there is actually no need to store this data in the database.

In the code, it would look like this:

```py
class Stock(models.Model):
    part_No = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    balance_bd = models.IntegerField(default='0', null = True)
    received = models.IntegerField(default='0', null = True)
    issued = models.IntegerField(default='0', null=True)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,  decimal_places=3, null=True)
    obsolete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    
    @property
    def total_bal(self):
        return self.balance_bd + self.received

    @property
    def tally_card_bal(self):
        return self.total_bal - self.issued

    @property
    def total_price(self):
        return self.tally_card_bal * self.unit_price
    
    ...
```

Note that I removed the model attributes for these values that were previously there. In the rest of the code, you can simply use these values as normal model attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much @vinkomlacic, your answer has solved the total_bal and the tally_card_bal calculation, the only problem I am facing now is that I am getting typeError which says "unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'"

Comment: Check if the operands are None and if so, assign 0 to them. You can also assign default values to all of the fields that can be null.

Comment: Yeah, I have resolved that. I realised I was have a None value in the unit_price and that was creating that problem so I deleted all the previous data I have entered and re-entered them after your solution and it worked perfectly. Thanks again.  You’ve been helpful to me and I’m very grateful